# Get the value of textLabel in a cell Swift 3

Tags: swift3, cell, uitableview, func

I have a tableview prototypecells, with a textLabel and a button, how can I get the value of the cell.textLabel using the cell button with a function instead of using tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath.

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply , you must be using an array for displaying data.

On button click get indexpath using

```
var center: CGPoint = sender.center
var rootViewPoint: CGPoint? = sender.superview?.convertPoint(center, to: filterTableView)
var indexPath: IndexPath? = filterTableView.indexPathForRow(at: rootViewPoint)
```

Now value of the cell.textLabel can be found by passing this indexPath in array as,

```
let string = array[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: x, section: 1)
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell
let text = cell?.textLabel.text
```